# How to test if an output of a third-party component is calling the right function on event in angular5

Tags: angular, angular5, karma-jasmine

Lets say i am using material autocomplete as so:

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <input #newroomInput matInput  [matAutocomplete]="autoGroup" [formControl]="newsRoomCtrl">
        <mat-autocomplete #autoGroup="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)='onNewsRoomSelect($event.option.value); newroomInput.value=""'>
          <mat-option *ngFor="let newsroomsource of filteredNewsRoomSources | async" [value]="newsroomsource"  >
            <span>{{ newsroomsource.sourceName }}</span> |
            <small>Type: {{ newsroomsource.sourceType }}</small>
          </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
      </mat-form-field>
```

How do I make sure `<mat-autocomplete>`'s `optionSelected` event calling  the right function

```
 it('should call onNewsRoomSelect on autocomplete optionselect event', () => {

    //Spy on comp.onNewsRoomSelect(selectedNewsRoom: NewsRoomSource);
    //DElibratedly fire event comp.optionSelected)=()
   //check if onNewsRoomSelect() is called

  });
```